# Quick paste via single keybind

Tags: gvim, cut-copy-paste, linux

As I understand, the default cursor looks like this: ▉ block. Currently I have these related settings:

```
set guicursor=c-n-i-v:ver25-blinkoff0
```

And

```
ver25
```

makes the cursor look and behave as if only right side of primary cursor form. So this commands mapping does not work (but the button 'Paste' in UI in GVIM works well though):

```
imap <C-v> <Esc>"+gPa
```

I need to leave only left side of it, I mean it is necessary that pasting occurs alltime only from left-to-right direction.

```
warning: gvim-8.1.1186-1 is up to date
5.1.3-arch1-1-ARCH
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the cursor, but I would try `imap <c-v> <c-r>+`. See `:help i_CTRL-R`.

Comment: @Ralf your mapping works, thanks.
I have to write also these two binds for deleting selected and switching in insert mode, because `<C-r>` cannot be rebinded.
`nmap <C-v> a`
`vmap <C-v> "_dha`